# How to give spacing in field name and value pair for the data coming from php?

Tags: php, css

I am working on a website in which I want to give spacing in field name coming from php code:

```
"rental_rates": [{
    "term": "daily",
     "rate": "56.00"  
}, {
    "term": "weekly",
    "rate": "677.00"
}]
```

The php code which I have used in order to extract the **field name** and **value** is:

```
<?php
   foreach ($data['item']->rental_rates as $rental_rate)
   {
   echo '<span class="rental_price">'.$rental_rate->term.': </span>';
   echo '<span class="">$'.floatval($rental_rate->rate).'</span><br>';
   }
   //echo $data['item']->rental_rates[0]->term.':'.$data['item']->rental_rates[0]->rate;
   //echo $data['item']->rental_rates[1]->term.':'.$data['item']->rental_rates[0]->rate;
   //echo $data['item']->rental_rates[2]->term.':'.$data['item']->rental_rates[0]->rate;
   //echo $data['item']->rental_rates[3]->term.':'.$data['item']->rental_rates[0]->rate;
   ?>
```

The above php code gives the following **o/p:**

```
rates:

daily:     $56 
weekly:    $677
```

Problem Statement:

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that I get the following o/p:

```
rates:

 daily:     $56 
weekly:    $677
```

Comment: this is not vaild json

Comment: `echo '<span class="rental_price" style="text-align:right;">'.$rental_rate->term.': </span>';`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON is a data transport format that requires field names to be string delimited with double quotes

Comment: Looks more like a CSS issue than anything else.

Comment: @VasimVanzara My apologies for that. Yeah, I agree thats not a valid JSON. I will edit my question

Comment: This is a table and should be styled as such.

Comment: or set the left spans width to fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     foreach ($data['item']->rental_rates as $rental_rate)
   {
   echo '<div style="text-align: left;">'.$data['item'].'</div>';  
   echo '<span class="rental_price" style="text-align:right">'.$rental_rate->term.': </span>';
   echo '<span class="" style="text-align:right">$'.floatval($rental_rate->rate).'</span><br>';
   }
```

Comment: As I see you get an output you make it formated. replace above code and check.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix the value. The value is still the same although the field name is aligned properly.

Comment: you need to make html span float left. that's not here.

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: so what is your expected output?

Comment: Check my problem statement. My expected o/p should look like the same. With your code, only the left half is fixed.

Comment: what is OP of  data['item'][0]; ??  data['item'][1];??

Comment: I have modified my problem statement. Your php code gives that o/p. I will edit in 2 min what o/p I want.